# Where is the top new free games on play store?

Tags: google-play-store

Does someone knows what going on with the Google Play store? Can't seem to find the top new free game in there anymore so I can't play newest game anymore and only able to see the same old trending games

[image]

Where can I see latest added games now?

Edit

Here's what it was supposed to look like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Google deleted this section from mobile client about 2 month ago. However, you still can access it via web, for example https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/GAME_RACING/collection/topselling_new_free
Yes, for devs it's sucks. Now it's harder to reach users than before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have it either, I never even noticed that section.
However, when you open Games on the play store you will have this (I don't know how to call it). Maybe this helps.

[image]

I took a look on another phone which has an older version of the store (7.1.25) and there isn't the section you asked about....

Comment: I've edited my post with the old store page where top new paid and top new free was in it.

Comment: @Warface well I couldn't find the category anywhere so it's probably removed by google.

Comment: As a developer... This sucks. Now how can we show our new release game if it no more avalaible to the public... Nice move Google... Nice move...